# PHP, grab entries in an array to make a new array

Tags: php

I have a problem and i'm not sure how to fix it.

It's quite different from anything I have done before.

I got this array:

```
array (
'DayTime_s' => '12:38',
'MATCHTIMEOUT_f' => '120.000000',
'MOD0_s' => '746138492',
'MOD1_s' => '841244723',
'MOD2_s' => '741155722',
'MOD3_s' => '748747466',
'ModId_l' => '0',
'Networking_i' => '1',
'NUMOPENPUBCONN' => '40',
)
```

The size of the array is different from one array to the next.
What I need is a new array, containing all "MOD?_s" entries above (with values). But the number of "mods" is different from one array to another. The numbers always increment by one though, starting from 0 (0,1,2,3,4 etc.)

How should I handle this task?

, Kenneth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$your_array = array (
'DayTime_s' => '12:38',
'MATCHTIMEOUT_f' => '120.000000',
'MOD0_s' => '746138492',
'MOD1_s' => '841244723',
'MOD2_s' => '741155722',
'MOD3_s' => '748747466',
'ModId_l' => '0',
'Networking_i' => '1',
'NUMOPENPUBCONN' => '40',
);

$new_array = [];
foreach($your_array as $key => $val)
    if(preg_match('/MOD\d+_s/ui', $key))
        $new_array[$key] = $val;

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: That was fast. Already tested it and it works flawless! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can also use [array_keys()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [unset()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) :

```
foreach( array_keys($the_array) as $key)
{
    if (!preg_match('/MOD\d+/s', $key)) {
        unset($the_array[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($test_array);
```

---

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [MOD0_s] => 746138492
    [MOD1_s] => 841244723
    [MOD2_s] => 741155722
    [MOD3_s] => 748747466
)
```